# How to import remote js file(which has attributes) in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, subresource-integrity

I want to use leaflet API and it needs the following script tag.

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
```

Now Require and getScript allows you to add the js files that we need to include but how do i add the integrity attribute.
I don't have access to html, so can we add the integrity and crossorigin attributes while we include js files with getScript or require.

Comment: Adding the attributes is the issue. I definitely have no problem with including the js file if you read carefully.

Comment: Please look again on the link. The first answer tells you directly how: `whatevert.setAttribute('integrity','sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==');`